# How do I rotate an object so that it's always facing the mouse position?

Tags: rust, nalgebra

I'm using ggez to make a game with some friends, and I'm trying to have our character rotate to face the pointer at all times. I know so far that I need to get an angle value (f32) in radians, and I think I can use atan2 to get this (?) However, I just don't get the behavior that I want.

This is the code I have: (btw, move_data is a struct holding our player character's values, such as position, velocity, angle and rotation speed).

```
let m = mouse::position(ctx);
move_data.angle = ((m.y - move_data.position.y).atan2(move_data.position.x - m.x)) * (consts::PI / 2.0) as f32;
```

I think that I'm close, as I'm already able with this to rotate the character, but only in a sort of 'incomplete' way. The player character (pc) can mostly only face to the upper left corner, when I move the mouse there. Otherwise, if the pointer is to the right and/or below the pc, it rotates in a very slow and minor way, and stops facing the pointer. I don't know if this description makes sense.

I think the problem is that I'm not entirely sure what atan2 is doing in the first place (I only remember some basic trigonometry), and I am also not sure if I'm using it correctly, so I don't exactly know what my code is doing. (Here is the documentation I used for atan2: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.atan2)

I've gotten only so far after much trial and error, Googling as much as I can (mostly Unity tutorial results showed up when looking for algorithms to base my code off of) and I've also asked in the unofficial Rust community Discord server, but nothing so far has worked.

I also had this code earlier, but couldn't find how to make it work either.

```
let m = mouse::position(ctx); // Type Point2
let mouse_pos = Vector2::new(m.x, m.y); // Transformed to Vector2 to be read by Matrix
move_data.angle = Matrix::angle(&mouse_pos, &move_data.position);
```

Comment: Why the multiplication with `pi / 2`? `atan2` gives the angle in radians

Comment: Also this seems to be a math problem instead of a rust problem